# presento problemas para imprimir un ticket con HTML y Javascript ¿podria alguien guiarme?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, eventos, javascript-metodo

presenatare mis dos documentos uno de Html y otro de JS, mi objetiovo es impimir un ticket con la con el costo de vuelo de un viaje dependiento si es ida o vuelta, y de la cantidad de boletos, pero no logro que me imprima y la vez que lo logre no me dio bien el valor del precio, ni los asientos, ni si era ida o ida y vuelta, tambien quisiera que por cada boleto a parte del asiento me dejara agregar la informacion personal del usuario de dicho asiento pero no tengo una idea clara de como hacer eso.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Compra de Boletos de Avión</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Compra de Boletos de Avión</h1>
    <form onsubmit="return validarFecha()">
      <label for="flightTypeSelect">Tipo de Vuelo:</label>
      <select id="flightTypeSelect">
        <option value="">-- Seleccione una opción --</option>
        <option value="Ida">Ida</option>
        <option value="Ida y Vuelta">Ida y Vuelta</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <label for="departureDateInput">Fecha de Ida:</label>
      <input type="date" id="departureDateInput" />
      <br />
      <div id="returnDateDiv" style="display:none">
        <label for="returnDateInput">Fecha de Regreso:</label>
        <input type="date" id="returnDateInput" />
        <br />
      </div>
      <label for="ticketCountInput">Cantidad de Boletos:</label>
      <input type="number" id="ticketCountInput" min="1" max="5" />
      <br>
      <label for="asientos">Selecciona los asientos para cada boleto:</label>
      <br>
      <div id="asientos-selects"></div>
      
      <br />
  
      <br />
      <label for="firstNameInput">Nombre:</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstNameInput" />
      <br />
      <label for="lastNameInput">Apellido:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastNameInput" />
      <br />
      <label for="idNumberInput">Número de Identidad:</label>
      <input type="text" id="idNumberInput" />
      <br />
      <button type="submit" id="buyButton" >Comprar</button>
    </form>
    <div id="receiptDiv"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y el de JS

```
//Definimos las variables globales que usaremos a lo largo del programa.
let precioVuelo = null
const destino1 = 'Matruin - Caracas'//Destino
const horaSalidaMaturin = '3:30 pm'//Horario de salida
const horaSalidaCaracas = '5:45 pm'
const numAsientos = 100;//Numero maximos de asientos

//Obtenemos los elementos del DOM con los que interactua el Usuario.
const tipoVueloSelecc = document.getElementById("flightTypeSelect");
const fechaSalida = document.getElementById("departureDateInput");
const fechaRegreso = document.getElementById("returnDateInput");
const asientoNumSelecc = document.getElementById("seatNumberSelect");
const numTickets = document.getElementById("ticketCountInput");
const nombre = document.getElementById("firstNameInput");
const apellido = document.getElementById("lastNameInput");
const idnum = document.getElementById("idNumberInput");
const botonComprar = document.getElementById("buyButton");
const recibo = document.getElementById("receiptDiv");
const fechaRetornoDiv = document.getElementById("returnDateDiv");

//definimos el valor del voleto dependiento del vuelo
if(tipoVueloSelecc.value === "Ida y vuelta"){
  precioVuelo = 50;
}
else{
  precioVuelo = 100;
}

// Modificamos el array de asientos para que cada elemento sea un objeto con una propiedad 'numeroAsiento' y una propiedad 'reservado'
const asientos = [...Array(numAsientos)].map((elem, i) => {
  return {
    numeroAsiento: i + 1,
    reservado: false
  }
});

function asignarAsientos() {
  // Obtener la cantidad de boletos seleccionados
  numTickets = parseInt(document.getElementById("ticketCountInput").value);

  // Obtener los valores seleccionados en los selects de asientos
  const asientosSeleccionados = [];
  const selects = document.querySelectorAll("#asientos-selects select");
  for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    asientosSeleccionados.push(selects[i].value);
  }

  // Verificar que no se hayan seleccionado asientos duplicados
  const asientosUnicos = [...new Set(asientosSeleccionados)];
  if (asientosUnicos.length < numTickets) {
    alert("No puedes seleccionar el mismo asiento para más de un boleto.");
    return;
  }

  // Asignar los asientos a los boletos
  const boletosAsignados = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numTickets; i++) {
    boletosAsignados.push(asientosSeleccionados[i]);
  }

  // Mostrar los asientos asignados
  alert(`Tus asientos asignados son: ${boletosAsignados.join(", ")}`);
}

function generarSelectAsientos(numBoletos) {
  const container = document.getElementById("asientos-selects");
  container.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < numBoletos; i++) {
    const select = document.createElement("select");
    for (let j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = `Asiento ${j}`;
      option.text = `Asiento ${j}`;
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
    container.appendChild(select);
  }
}


numTickets.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{

  generarSelectAsientos(e.target.value);
})

// agregar evento change al elemento select
tipoVueloSelecc.addEventListener("change", () => {
  // mostrar u ocultar div dependiendo de la selección del usuario
  if (tipoVueloSelecc.value === "Ida y Vuelta") {
    fechaRetornoDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    fechaRetornoDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
});

//LLenamos el Selecc con los asientos disponibles.
asientos.forEach(asiento => {
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = asiento.numeroAsiento;
  option.text = `Asiento ${asiento.numeroAsiento}`;
  asientoNumSelecc.add(option);
});

//validar la fecha.

fechaSalida.addEventListener("change", e =>{
  validarFecha();
})
fechaRegreso.addEventListener("change", e =>{
  validarFecha();
})

function validarFecha() {
    const departureDate = new Date(fechaSalida.value);
    const hoy = new Date();
    const timeDiff = departureDate.getTime() - hoy.getTime();
    const diffDays = timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  
    if (departureDate < hoy || diffDays < 1) {
      alert("La fecha de salida debe ser posterior a hoy.");
      return false;
    }
  
    return true;
  }

// Función que valida si todos los campos están llenos
function validateForm() {
  if (!tipoVueloSelecc.value || !numTickets.value || !nombre.value || !apellido.value || !idnum.value) {
    alert("Por favor llene todos los campos."); // Mostramos un mensaje de error si algún campo está vacío
    return false;
  }

  if (!asientoNumSelecc.value) {
    alert("Por favor seleccione un asiento."); // Mostramos un mensaje de error si no se ha seleccionado un asiento
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

// Función que se llama cuando se hace clic en el botón de Comprar
botonComprar.addEventListener("click",e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
    asignarAsientos();
    buyTikects();
})
  
function buyTikects(){
  if (!validateForm()) {
    return; // Salimos de la función si hay algún error
  }
  else{
  if(tipoVueloSelecc === "oneWay"){
    flightType = "Ida";
  }
  else{
    flightType = "Ida y vuelta";
  }
  const departureDate = fechaSalida.value ? new Date(fechaSalida.value) : null; // Obtenemos la fecha de ida
  const returnDate = fechaRegreso.value ? new Date(fechaRegreso.value) : null; // Obtenemos la fecha de regreso si es que existe
  const ticketCount = parseInt(numTickets.value); // Obtenemos la cantidad de boletos
  const firstName = nombre.value.trim(); // Obtenemos el nombre del comprador y le quitamos los espacios al inicio y al final
  const lastName = apellido.value.trim(); // Obtenemos el apellido del comprador y le quitamos los espacios al inicio y al final
  const idNumber = idnum.value.trim(); // Obtenemos el número de identidad del comprador y le quitamos los espacios al inicio y al final

  // Creamos el objeto con la información de la compra
  const purchase = {
    destino1,
    horaSalidaMaturin,
    flightType,
    departureDate,
    returnDate,
    ticketCount,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    idNumber,
    seatNumber: asientoNumSelecc.value,
    totalPrice: (typeof precioVuelo !== 'undefined') ? precioVuelo * parseInt(numTickets) : NaN, // Calculamos el precio total de la compra
  };

  // Mostramos un mensaje de confirmación con la información de la compra
  const confirmation = confirm(`¿Está seguro de que desea comprar ${numTickets} boleto(s) para el vuelo ${tipoVueloSelecc}?`);
  if (!confirmation) {
    return; // Salimos de la función si el usuario no confirma la compra
  }

  // Actualizamos el array de asientos disponibles
  const seatIndex  = asientos.indexOf(parseInt(asientoNumSelecc.value));
  asientos.splice(seatIndex, 1);

  // Actualizamos el select de asientos para que no muestre el asiento que acaba de ser vendido
  asientoNumSelecc.remove(seatIndex + 1);

  // Creamos el recibo de compra
  const receipt = `
    <p><strong>Destino:</strong> ${purchase.destino1}</p>
    <p><strong>Hora de Salida:</strong> ${purchase.horaSalidaMaturin}</p>
    <p><strong>Tipo de Vuelo:</strong> ${purchase.flightType}</p>
    <p><strong>Fecha de Ida:</strong> ${purchase.departureDate ? purchase.departureDate.toLocaleDateString() : "N/A"}</p>
    <p><strong>Fecha de Regreso:</strong> ${purchase.returnDate ? purchase.returnDate.toLocaleDateString() : "N/A"}</p>
    <p><strong>Cantidad de Boletos:</strong> ${purchase.ticketCount}</p>
    <p><strong>Asiento:</strong> ${purchase.seatNumber}</p>
    <p><strong>Nombre del Comprador:</strong> ${purchase.firstName} ${purchase.lastName}</p>
    <p><strong>Número de Identidad:</strong> ${purchase.idNumber}</p>
    <p><strong>Precio Total:</strong> $${(!isNaN(purchase.totalPrice)) ? purchase.totalPrice.toFixed(2) : 'N/A'}</p>
  `;

  // Mostramos el recibo de compra en la página
  recibo.innerHTML = receipt;

  // Reiniciamos los campos del formulario
  tipoVueloSelecc.value = "";
  fechaSalida.value = "";
  fechaRegreso.value = "";
  asientoNumSelecc.value = "";
  numTickets.value = "";
  nombre.value = "";
  apellido.value = "";
  idNumber.value = "";
  asientoSeleccionado = null;

  alert("¡Gracias por su compra");
}
}
```

vengo para escuchar sus comentarios y opiniones y critcas estoy aprendiendo y voy algo lento con todo esto Gracias a aquellos que me puedan colaborar.

Comment: Imprimir en pantalla o en la impresora?

Comment: imprimir en pantalla

Comment: Formula mejor tu pregunta, agrega puntos como 1. Necesito imprimir y este es el codigo que imprime, 2. Necesito que los calculos sean correctos y este es el codigo que hace los calculos. Tu pregunta es muy dificil de leer y comprender. Solo agrega el codigo necesario identificado como defectuoso, no toda tu clase.